# Wrapping class with pure virtual methods

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, wrapper, word-wrap

I have an unmanaged dll which contains a class with pure virtual methods only (kind of callbacks):

```
class PAClient
{
public:
    __declspec(dllexport) virtual void SetCalculationStarted() = 0;     
    __declspec(dllexport) virtual void SetCalculationStopped() = 0; 
}
```

Now I have to send these function calls to the managed C# code and decided to use interface for that. This is what I've done:

```
public interface class IPAClientWrapper
{
    void SetCalculationStarted();       
    void SetCalculationStopped();   
};

private class PAClientWrapper : public PAClient
{
private:
    gcroot<IPAClientWrapper^> callBack;

public:

    PAClientWrapper(IPAClientWrapper^ c)
    {
        callBack = c;
    }

    void SetCalculationStarted()
    {
        callBack->SetCalculationStarted();
    }

    void SetCalculationStopped()
    {
        callBack->SetCalculationStopped();
    }
}
```

But every time the **unmanaged** `SetCalculationStarted()` is called, the unmanaged code throws an exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in PAnalysisLib.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

**EDIT:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IPAClientWrapper
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetCalculationStarted()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("started");
    }

    public void SetCalculationStopped()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("stopped");
    }
```

}

Do I miss something?

Comment: I'm really not sure but maybe it doesn't know how to call the pure virtual methods since they don't have a definition. Have you tried it with a subclass that does define them?

Comment: Can you inherit from an unmanaged class? You cannot create an object of a pure virtual native class.

Comment: @dutt the thing that I tried to achieve is to forward the function calls to C#, there I do implement IPAClientWrapper interface. implementation of IPAClientWrapper should be definition for these virtual methods. Do I understand the thing correctly?

Comment: @qPCR4vir this is C++/CLI, the code is compiled without errors, so I guess I can inherit it. Where did I create an object of it?

Comment: You need to make sure both your C# and C++ code is using the same calling convention. Furthermore where is your C# code?

Comment: @Ramhound I've added the C# code, doubt it will help someone to answer my question. There is no need to specify calling convention as SetCalculationStarted and SetCalculationStopped are callback functions so they must be fired from the unmanaged code and forwarded to the managed.

Comment: @VladL - Something...is causing your code to attempt to read protected memory.  Your implementation doesn't make a greal deal of sense to be honest.

Comment: @Ramhound could you recommend a better one?

Comment: All of this looks ok to me. Trap the exception in a debugger; you have a lot more information about your problem that we do.